# How to check format of a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, validation, format

I'm quite new to javascript and I can't find a single guide how to check string format (except whole code how to check e-mail etc).

So I need to check if my variable is in this format - applicationcode0001.
The text is not going to change - so something like this - `variable=="applicationcode"+[number]+[number]+[number]+[number]`

If you can provide me some link how to check string variables like that, I will be super happy.

Thanks,
MJ

Comment: [MDN: Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: Use a regular expression.

Comment: thanks, that's what i needed and didnt know how to name it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var myRe = /^applicationcode\d{4}$/;
console.log(myRe.test('applicationcode0001'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
    var regex = RegExp('applicationcode[0-9]{4}','g');
    var str1 = 'applicationcode1234';

    console.log(regex.test(str1));
    // expected output: true
    //
```